# Include/exclude files depending on target (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, target

Is it possible to include/exclude certain source files depending on what target is selected in Visual Studio? If possible, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by having a `define` in the beginning of the relevant source files. Add a unique identifier to each build configuration, and wrap your source file with:

```
#if _MY_IDENTIFER
...
#endif
```

If you want a more robust way, switch so by using [nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
Right click on the file you want to exclude and select Properties. You can now set Action to None according to the target.